# PIG: Process tuples in a bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data set that looks like this after a GROUP operation :

```
input = key1|{(a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2)}
        key2|{(a3,b3,c3),(a4,b4,c4),(a5,b5,c5)}
```

I need to traverse the above to generate final output like this :

```
<KEY>key1</KEY>|
<VALUES><VALUE><VALUE1>a1</VALUE1>VALUE2>b1</VALUE2>VALUE3>c1</VALUE3></VALUE><VALUE><VALUE1>a2</VALUE1><VALUE2>b2</VALUE2><VALUE3>c2</VALUE3>    </VALUE></VALUES>
 <KEY>key2</KEY>| ...
```

I have tried to use FLATTEN and CONCAT to achieve this result in the below manner:

```
A = FOREACH input GENERATE key, FLATTEN(input);
output = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT('<KEY>',CONCAT(input.key,'</KEY>')),
                            CONCAT('<VALUE>',''),
                            CONCAT('<VALUE1>',CONCAT(input.col1,'</VALUE1>')
                            ...
```

But this does not give the desired output. Fairly new to pig, so don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you FLATTEN your bag than you'll ended up as many new 'rows' as many elements you had in the bag:

```
key1|(a1,b1,c1)
key1|(a2,b2,c2)
```

If I understand your problem correctly you want this:

Use the [BagToTuple](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html) built in function.

Than you'll get

```
key1|(a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2)
```

After this you can format your data with e.g. a UDF